# 2 broadband modems and one dumb switch

Tags: networking, internet, modem

I would need your help with something.

I have small office, but all our work is online. To have secure internet connection, I have 2 different internet providers at my office. And if something happens to one, I need to disconnect one internet and connect another modem which is online - so manual labor :) . 
We are using 24p dumb switch for the office.

My question is ( please, bear in mind that I know something, but for this matter I will say - I am beginner ): 
Can I connect both modems ( again, they are both on separate internet providers ) on that switch and have stable internet connection on all PC's, and even if one goes down, will others get new IP from other modem? Or there will be some crossfire and all will go haywire?

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

As the switch is dumb, I'm presuming you're using DHCP from one of the routers provided by your ISPs. If you're going to connect both of them, you'll want to turn the DHCP off on the other one.

You simply need to change the gateway assigned by the router to be the correct one that's working at that time. Then everyone would need to do a DHCP refresh either by rebooting their own machine, or using command prompt and doing `ipconfig /renew`.

There are more complicated ways of achieving this however they'll require you spending on equipment to do it properly.

Comment: Thank you for your help.In addition, I have Edge-X router, which is unused in box. I had issues creating WAN port on it, so I gave up on it. 
If that router can be used, to somehow deal internet from both modems, that would be great ( as you said - extra spending :) ) 

Regarding your answer, I need to connect from one modem to another and then get out to a network. When one fails, another will continue with dealing the "internet" while the one with DHCP enabled, will deal IP's to users?